# How to use livereload with Webpack in Electron?

Tags: angular, webpack, electron, livereload

I'm trying to integrate Electron into the [Akveo's ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin), and I already had webpack config files for the Angular app, as well the Electron platform, you can actually look the integration [here](https://github.com/michaeljota/ng2-admin).

What I'm trying now it's to get live reload capabilities. The scripts right now will package the electron application as build.

My idea it's to have couple scenarios that can be covered with `npm` scripts, like:

- Live reload of the Angular application inside the Electron platform.
- Live reload of the complete solution, with Electron live self reload.

Those two would work well, I think.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to the my Angular 2 integration with Webpack and Electron [here](https://github.com/osechet/angular-tour-of-heroes-webpack). The project is based on the Angular 2 tutorial. When using Electron in development mode (`npm run start.desktop`), webpack livereloads the code.

I also created a quickstart project: https://github.com/osechet/angular-webpack-quickstart

Comment: This is my current implementation [angular2-ultimate-starter](https://github.com/michaeljota/angular2-ultimate-starter)

It does the reload, but I can't reload only the render part when the webpack rebuilds it, have to reload the whole application.

Does your solution only reload the renderer side when just the renderer  files had change?

Comment: @MichaelJota I tested and this does reload just the renderer when the browser app changes, and it restarts electron when the main process is updated. None of the other Electron/Angular2 boilerplates do this the right way.

Comment: Yes, as @ColinSkow said, with this implementation, webpack watches the renderer files and the main files independently. If a renderer file changes, the electron window content is reloaded. If the main files are updated, the whole app is restarted.